# Open and edit given .js file and replace placeholder using GitHub action

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

In my Github workflow, using YML, I want to open a given.js file, the file could be main.23232323.js and I want to search for a file which starts with main**, also I want to search for placeholders like <>, and <>, and replace them with URLs I want, and save it.

I have just started with it like below but not sure how to search for a specific pattern file and how to replace it.

```
jobs:
  testJob:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - id: set_var
        run: |
          content=`cat ./path/to/package.json`
```

Comment: If it's a .`js` file, can you simply not use values from the environment variables?